# 1Inch with flashloan provider

Tags: uniswap, ethereum-wallet-dapp, cpp-ethereum, sushiswap, 1inch-dex-aggregator

Is there a way to trade on 1Inch using the API and flash-loaned balance. If it is possible please give me some info. I was seeing the DOC to find how to integrate the flash-loan provider with 1Inch when swapping using the API and i can not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to trade using flash-loan and 1inch API is, write a solidity smart contract that receives the call-data from 1inch's API `swap` endpoint, then loan the amount required and finally place order using the call-data. But to do this `disableEstimate` must be `false`in 1inch API to prevent `insufficient balance` error.